# Why am I geting an error while trying to use relation on FOAF?

Tags: xml, rdf, semantic-web, foaf

I am trying to validate a foaf code on [W3C RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) and the from following block it is causing problem. Here I am trying to show relation between Randy and Adil, please currect me why I can't use "rel" tag here or why is it causing problem?

```
<foaf:knows>
        <foaf:Person>

        <foaf:name>Randy</foaf:name>

        <foaf:mbox_sha1sum>0525a7bfaf263d404e751bb12b89e4acc1ce68a7</foaf:mbox_sha1sum>
        <rdfs:workplaceHomepage rdf:resource="randy.html" />
    <rel:friendOf rdf:resource="adil.html"/>        
  </foaf:Person>
    </foaf:knows>
```

Error:

```
FatalError: The prefix "rel" for element "rel:friendOf" is not bound.[Line = 39, Column = 46]
```

Comment: consider asking on answers.semanticweb.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the FOAF content in an `RDF` element that declares the appropriate namespaces:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
     xmlns:rel="http://www.perceive.net/schemas/relationship/">
```

Comment: What if I need to show relation like "loves" "likes" and so on?

Comment: @Himalay: there seem to be no such relationships in `rel`. You could define your own relationships, perhaps as subproperties of those of http://www.perceive.net/schemas/20031015/relationship/relationship.rdf, but then your file might not work with FOAF APIs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the namespace `rel` in the same way that you must have specified `foaf` at the top of your RDF/XML document.

This example should work for you ...

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
         xmlns:rel="http://some.namespace.for.rel.com/ns/"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         >
 <foaf:Person>
   <foaf:name>Peter Parker</foaf:name>
   <foaf:mbox rdf:resource="mailto:peter.parker@dailybugle.com"/>
    <foaf:knows>
        <foaf:Person>
        <foaf:name>Randy</foaf:name>
        <foaf:mbox_sha1sum>0525a7bfaf263d404e751bb12b89e4acc1ce68a7</foaf:mbox_sha1sum>
        <rdfs:workplaceHomepage rdf:resource="randy.html" />
    <rel:friendOf rdf:resource="adil.html"/>        
      </foaf:Person>
    </foaf:knows>
 </foaf:Person>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Anyway the use you make of `rdfs:workplaceHomepage` is wrong, you should use `foaf:workplaceHomepage` and also `rel:friendOf` doesn't make much sense. You can use `foaf:knows` here also.